# How to handle datetime vlaues in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a datetime in format = '2020-05-01'. I want the output to be 2020-05-01 00:00:00.

I use this simple code to achieve this but I am missing the time part.

```
datetime.strptime(month, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I am using python2. Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this. This seems like a really simple problem but for some reason I am not able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your one line of code already generates a datetime value which should be set to midnight (the default value for no explicit time component).  If you want to *view* this data with its time component, then use `strftime` with an appropriate format mask:

```
month = '2020-05-01'
dt = datetime.strptime(month, "%Y-%m-%d")
dt_out = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(dt_out)
```

This prints:

```
2020-05-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = datetime.strptime(month, "%Y-%m-%d")
x.strftime(month, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Source:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime